# UIWebView URL from String without http://

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk

So I check if the string starts with **"http://"** using the code below, and then I want to add **"http://"** so that I'm able to open the page in `UIWebView`.

```
NSString *firstString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", URL.text];
NSString *check = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://"];

if (firstString != check) {
    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", URL.text];
    newString = [newString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(7, newString.length - 7)];
    URL.text = newString;
}

[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL.text]]];`
```

This doesn't work for some reason.
Do you know why?

Comment: Your making this too difficult. Just use hasPrefix to check if the string starts with http.

Comment: Use `isEqualToString:` to compare strings. Unlike C/C++, If you write it like that they will never be equal since you are really comparing their pointer.

Comment: After hasPrefix consider this: NSString* prefix = @"http://"; URL = [prefix stringByAppendingString:URL];

Comment: @ShaneHsu, Oh yes, that is the reason you aren't comparing them correctly. That took me a while to remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somebody posted as I was writing, but either way, here's an answer:

You are making this too difficult. You simply need to use hasPrefix to check for "http". As an example, I use this for my unified search/url bar.

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
    NSString *inputString = [searchField stringValue];
    NSString *outputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

    if ([inputString hasPrefix:@"http://"]) {
        //Has Prefix
        [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:inputString]]];
    }
    else
    {
        //Does not have prefix. Do what you want here. I google it.
        NSString *googleString = @"http://google.com/search?q=";
        NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", googleString, outputString];
        [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchString]]];

    }

}
```

That is for googling instead, you could keep using `NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", URL.text];`

You could add a few more checks as well if you wanted to. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, this is for Cocoa not Cocoa Touch, but the checking works the same. Ignore the part about loading the webView.

Comment: Don't forget to put a check by an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

`firstString != check` checks to see if both objects point to the same location in memory. `[firstString isEqualToString:check]` checks if the two strings are equal. However, what you most likely want to do is `if(![firstString hasPrefix:check])`. This will check to make sure firstString does not start with check, then you can append check to the start of it. Alternatively, you can do `firstString = [firstString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];`, and then you know it will never start with @"http://"

Answer (score 0):

Try printing what URL.text is before the loadRequest line via `NSLog(@"%@",URL.text);`
Also the preferred check condition would be `if (![firstString isEqualToString:check]) {}`